# Storing a binary number in a register; programming in MIPS

Tags: assembly, binary, integer, mips

I'm taking a course where we're exploring MIPS, so I'm very new with programming in assembly. I'm experimenting and trying to convert an integer value to binary and then store this value to a register (or just outright return it as a string to console using a syscall). Could someone please outline the process for me? (Preferably in bare instructions).

So far my understanding is to use a division routine that properly acquires the bits of the integer in binary, which I have done using division by 2 and storing the remainder--but I have no idea how to append this remainder to an already existing chain of bits.

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you are trying to do (what is input and output format, which is text, which is binary). Either way, there are gazillions of examples.

Comment: What is the input you start with? On MIPS registers are of `word` size, which is 32 bits. By convention the two's complement encoding is used to encode integer values in them, i.e. `li $t1,9` (or how is that instruction to load immediate value into register, check your MIPS instruction set guide) means that from the 32 bits of `t1` registers the first "b0" and fourth "b3" bits are set, others are clear. So if you have integer value in register, you already have it split into binary encoding, because that's how CPU \*usually\* works with integers in registers (unless you use custom encoding).

Comment: So to output that as string of digits 0 and 1 you need only to test each bit separately from top "b31" down to lowest "b0", and output either 0 or 1 according to the particular bit state. No division+remainder needed (also for any other base which is power of two, like hexadecimal formatting, then single digit is equal to the group of four bits, or octal when single digit is three bits). You need division+remainder for other bases, like 10 or 12, etc. For bit checking there are common bitwise operations like `and`, `or`, `xor` and shift left/right instructions.

Comment: To that first comment one more note... why bits.. because single bit is physically one "cell" or "wire", where the electricity current level denotes whether the bit is set, or clear. And all the common digital CPUs are built upon that base, so registers are 32 bits physically, on the CPU chip, it's not some kind of fictional way to imagine binary numbers, but actual electricity currents encoding all the things which computer can work with. What you see on other output devices, like text on screen or sound from speakers, those are processed + formatted original bit values as needed per device.

Comment: please add an example of what you want to do, for example do you want to load a register with 123 which is = 0x7b = 0b000...0001111011 ?  and exactly what format are you starting with a string (0x31,0x32,0x33,0x00) or something else?  Where is this value you want to convert stored?

Comment: Hey guys I apologize for the late reply. I was also pretty vague.

Basically without pseudo instructions I managed to build this garbage division subroutine that basically just divides a dividend by 2 and spits out the number in binary one bit at a time.

My question is how do I store the bits that my subroutine spits out such that I can return it through a syscall to the user? 

So if my subroutine dumped out 1 0 1 1, how do I "concatenate" those bits together to return as a string to the user as "1011" in console? Thanks for your replies!

Comment: Convert each bit to ascii by adding `'0'` then store it in an array.

Comment: Unless your environment has specialized output function capable to format value in binary, you will have to output it either char-by-char (if you have "output char"), or create whole string. Char-by-char => your platform does probably use ASCII or UTF8 encoding, so character `'0'` is value 48 and `'1'` is value 49, i.e. your bit value 0/1 + '0' = character to output. And one character is 1 byte (UTF8 has multi-byte chars, but not for digits, ASCII is only 1B). To get string you need some spare memory buffer big enough to store such characters into it, then output whole buffer at once.